# How do I validate with jQuery if two select box combination was already used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have a group of two select boxes, and I can clone that by pressing a button "Add more". The problem is, the combination can't be used again. So, if I choose `"Book"` on the first and `"Classic"` on the second, I can't choose it anymore.

Check a demo here: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rafaelsantos/dtrx33fg/)

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="box">
            <select name="area_id[1]" id="area_id_1" class="area">
                <option value="0" disabled selected>Select an area...</option>
                <option value="1" >Literature</option>
                <option value="2" >Music</option>
                <option value="3" >Cinema</option>
            </select>
            <select name="genre_id[1]" id="genre_id_1" class="genre">
                <option value="0" disabled selected>Select a genre...</option>
                <option value="1" >Classic</option>
                <option value="2" >2000+</option>
                <option value="3" >Portuguese</option>
            </select>
            <hr>
    </div>
<span class="add">Click to Add More</span>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var attrs = ['id'];
function resetAttributeNames(section, action) { 
  var index = section.prevAll('.box').length;
  var tags = section.find('select'), idx = index + 1;
  tags.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if(action === 'add'){
      $this.find('option[value="0"]').attr('disabled', true); 
      $this.find('option[value="0"]').attr('selected', true); 
    } 
    $.each(attrs, function(i, attr) {
      var attr_val = $this.attr(attr);
      var name = $this.attr('name');
      if (attr_val) {
        $this.attr(attr, attr_val.replace(/_\d+$/, '_'+(idx)));
        $this.attr('name', name.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/, '['+idx+']'));
      }                    
     });
   });
}

$('.add').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.box').last();
  var cloned = lastRepeatingGroup.clone(true);
  cloned.insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup);
  resetAttributeNames(cloned, 'add');           
});
```

**What I tried:**

```
$('.box').change(function() {
            var this_id = $(this).attr('id');
            var this_pos = getNumber($(this).attr('name'));
            $('.area').each(function(){
                var other_select_pos = getNumero($(this).attr('name'));
                if($('#area_id_'+other_select_pos).val() === $('#'+this_id).val()){
                    var unselectable = $('#genre_id_'+other_select_pos).val();
                    $('#genre_id_'+this_pos+' option').each(function() {
                        if($(this).val() === unselectable){
                            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
        })

        function getNumber(name){
            var regExp = /\[([^)]+)\]/;
            var matches = regExp.exec(name);
            return matches[1];
        }
```

But this code seems so wrong just by looking, and its not working properly. How can I do this simply and clean?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by `i can't choose it anymore`? It works as expected in the fiddle.

Comment: I don't want to be possible to choose the same combination more than one time. And right now, its possible to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to bind the `onchange` event for the `select` and see if that area-genre pair shows up more than once over all `.box`es

```
  $this.change(function () {
      var area = $this.parents(".box").find(".area").val();
      var genre = $this.parents(".box").find(".genre").val();
      var numFound = 0;
      $(".box").each(function () {
          var cur_area = $(".area", this).val();
          var cur_box = $(".genre", this).val();
          if (area === cur_area && cur_box === genre) {
              numFound += 1;
          }

      });

      if (numFound > 1) {
          alert("You already choose that " + (numFound - 1) + " times!");
      }
  });
```

You can see the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dtrx33fg/2/)